# Scala Spark Application is not exiting with proper status

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception

I am working on a spark stand alone application , which has a below code structure:

**code structure:**

```
jobStatus=Pass
try
{
calls rest API based on status it throws exception or success
}
catch{ 
catch all exceptions
jobStatus =Fail
}
finally
{
jobStatus match {
        //case Pass => System.exit(0)
        case Pass => return(0) 
        //case Fail => System.exit(1)
        case Fail => return(1) 
      }
}
```

So,if i use System.exit (0) or (1) the  spark application always exit with Failed Status(even though there is no exceptions).

If i use return(0) or (1) the spark application always ends with Success status(even though there is exception)

**Versions used :**

Scala Version : 2.11.0

Spark version: 2.2.0

**Spark log (return(0) or return(1) case:**

*INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext*

*INFO ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with **SUCCEEDED***

*INFO AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.*

*INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called*

**Spark log (System.exit(0) or System.exit(1) case:**

*INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext*

*INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 16, (reason: Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.)*

*INFO ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with **FAILED** (diag message: Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.)*

*INFO AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered*

I am looking for suggestions or  inputs to fix this scenario to  end the application with proper status. Let me know if you need any other details on this.

Comment: You might want to move your comments into your question. You can edit your question as often as you like

Comment: @werner , Done.....